# How to create a digital signature for the WIN10 x64 driver?

Tags: windows

I have a device from a silicone developer and WIN10x64. With this device comes the driver with a good digital signature. But I need to rename the device name "silicone cp210x" to my name "Example" in the device's installation driver. I'm using a utility - CustomUSBDriverWizard.exe to create a renamed installation driver, but the installer is created without a digital signature ".cat" file. Is there a way to create my digital signature for Windows or to adapt the driver certificate for the name of the "silicone cp210x" for my name  "Example"?
Disable digital signature verification or contact Microsoft for the digital signature of the driver with my name - these options do not need me. Perhaps there is a program for editing digital signatures of drivers or creating new digital signatures based on an inf. and sys. file?

Comment: Exactly why do you need to rename the driver?

Comment: "Perhaps there is a program for editing digital signatures of drivers or creating new digital signatures based on an inf. and sys. file?" - This does not exist.  You would have to create a new digital signature, to do that, would require a certificate that costs money.  So in order to avoid the X Y Z problem that you describe, what reason do you have, to rename the driver file?

Comment: This is needed to create a device based on a Chinese device, but the device must have my name

Answer (score 0):

I use this process to sign unsigned drivers for Win7. Its for repairing damaged .cat signature too.
I do not know if this still works for Win10.
You need the Windows Driver Kit.

Source:

https://www.richud.com/wiki/Windows_7_Install_Unsigned_Drivers_CAT_fix

In brief

1. Create a self signed certificate
2. Sign your modified driver (.cat) with the new certificate
3. Import the certificate to your Device
4. Install the driver